# (Tensorflow-GPU) import tensorflow ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'

Tags: python, tensorflow

After created tensorflow environment under anaconda, I installed tensorflow-gpu. Then I was trying to import tensorflow to verify if it's correctly installed, but got this error:

```
ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Note that installing cuDNN is a separate step from installing CUDA, and this DLL is often found in a different directory from the CUDA DLLs. You may install the necessary DLL by downloading cuDNN 7 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn
```

Setup is:

```
NVIDIA GTX 1080
CUDA 9.0
cuDNN 6.0
tensorflow-gpu 1.5
```

Environment Variables are:

```
CUDA_PAT: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0
CUDA_PATH_V9_0: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0
```

The %Path% variables are:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\lib\x64
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp
C:\Users\yshen\AppData\Local\cudnn-8.0-windows10-x64-v6.0\cuda\bin
```

it is obvious that I installed cuDNN6.0, don't why the error shows "Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll' ". Why it automatically searches cudnn64_7.dll instead of cudnn64_6.dll?

Comment: @janeshen please read this thread to solve the isse https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13442

Comment: [Here's an answer with all the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65524506/38368) for later versions of Tensorflow (requiring newer CUDA).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Also, I got below error when I installed `TensorFlow 1.8`. I have the Anaconda environment.

> "ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'"

But after I installed `Nvidia cuDNN v7.1.3` (April 17, 2018), for `CUDA 9.0`, everything started to work.
Please note that one needs to sign up as a Nvidia developer to be able to download the installation package(s).

Then, just follow the instructions in the page : [cudnn-install](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html)

For Windows:

3.3. Installing cuDNN on Windows

The following steps describe how to build a cuDNN dependent program. In the following sections:

-your CUDA directory path is referred to as `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0`

-your cuDNN directory path is referred to as `<installpath>`

1. Navigate to your `<installpath>` directory containing `cuDNN`.
2. Unzip the cuDNN package. `-cudnn-9.0-windows7-x64-v7.zip` or `-cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.zip`
3. Copy the following files into the CUDA Toolkit directory.

   - Copy `<installpath>\cuda\bin\cudnn64_7.dll` to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin`.
   - Copy `<installpath>\cuda\ include\cudnn.h` to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\include`.
   - Copy `<installpath>\cuda\lib\x64\cudnn.lib` to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\lib\x64`.
4. Set the following environment variables to point to where cuDNN is located. To access the value of the `$(CUDA_PATH)` environment variable, perform the following steps:

   - Open a command prompt from the Start menu.
   - Type Run and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   - Issue the control `sysdm.cpl` command.
   - Select the Advanced tab at the top of the window.
   - Click Environment Variables at the bottom of the window.
   - Ensure the following values are set:
     Variable Name:  `CUDA_PATH` 
     Variable Value: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0`
5. Include cudnn.lib in your Visual Studio project.

   - Open the Visual Studio project and `right-click` on the `project name`.
   - Click `Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`.
   - Add `cudnn.lib` and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: *Include cudnn.lib in your Visual Studio project.
    Open the Visual Studio project and right-click on the project name.
    Click Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.
    Add cudnn.lib and click `OK`.* I didn't understand how to do this step, can you explain please?

Comment: I have a weird issue. Whenever I import Tensorflow I get this error. But when I import torch along with tensorflow, it is able to open the same library without any issue.

Comment: It actually worked for me to do all steps except step 5. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to you previous answer, you seem to find out prebuilt tensorflow-gpu 1.5 is not compatible with CUDA 9.0 + CudNN 6.0. There are two possible solutions for your answer, if you want to use tensorflow-gpu 1.5:

1, upgrade your CUDA tool chain to CUDA 9.0 +Cudnn 7.0 (currently Cudnn 7.0.5 for CUDA 9.0).

2, recompile the tensorflow-gpu 1.5 target for CUDA 9.0 + cudnn 6.0.

I suggest choosing the first option for ease. But the official webpage of tensorflow 1.5 dose not deny the possibility of option 2:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case i needed to install old cuDNN libraries linked [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)

Comment: As suggested, I have found the file under this zip: cudnn-10.2-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32.zip.

Answer (score 0):

Just fould the solution:

I checked the \tensorflow\python\platform\build_info.py and found:

```
msvcp_dll_name = 'msvcp140.dll'
cudart_dll_name = 'cudart64_90.dll'
cuda_version_number = '9.0'
nvcuda_dll_name = 'nvcuda.dll'
cudnn_dll_name = 'cudnn64_7.dll'
cudnn_version_number = '7'
```

It assumes cudnn version is 7. So just need to correct it as:

```
cudnn_dll_name = 'cudnn64_6.dll'
cudnn_version_number = '6'
```

Comment: After applying the above solution, there was another error coccured when I was trying to import tensorflow. The error is: No Module Named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'.  After figuring out the cause, I realized the required versions of cuDNN(which is 6.0) doesn't match CUDA 9.0, as shown in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows. It should be CUDA 9.0 + cuDNN 7.0 (not cuDNN 6.0) .