# How to get tensorflow-gpu v2 working on Windows with NVidia GPU

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, nvidia

What are the steps to get `tensorflow-gpu` 2.x Python package working on Windows with an NVidia GPU?

I.e. how can I get rid of `Could not find 'cudart64_101.dll'` and then `Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Steps**

- Requires specific versions according to the error messages you see, **not** latest versions!

#### 1. Download and install latest NVidia driver

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

#### 2. Install Tensorflow Python package

```cmd
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

(*) For newer versions, `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` are the same package, so just update `tensorflow` using:

```
pip install --upgrade tensforflow
```

#### 3. Test

At first the following test will fail, pay attention to version of missing file e.g. `Could not find 'cudart64_101.dll'`

```python
import tensorflow

tensorflow.test.is_built_with_gpu_support() # Test install of pip package, should output True
tensorflow.test.is_gpu_available() # Should output True
tensorflow.test.gpu_device_name() # Should output something like /device:GPU:0
# update for last test:
tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

#### 4. Download and install CUDA Toolkit 10.1 **local** setup

- The version you need is the one not found e.g. cudart64_**101**.dll --> version **10.1**.
- You will need to unselect components because setup contains an older driver, in network setup this doesn't work right

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-base?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exelocal

Select custom setup and:

- **Un**select `CUDA` / `Visual Studio Integration`
- **Un**select `Driver components`

#### 5. Make sure these folders have been added to path:

- And no other versions of CUDA

```cmd
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp;
```

#### 6. Test again

- Restart your IDE for it to receive new environment variables (including PATH)

Will fail, pay attention to version of missing file e.g. `Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'`

#### 7. Download and manually install CUDNN 7.6.5 for CUDA 10.1

- The version you need is the one not found e.g. cudnn64_**7**.dll --> version **7**.x for CUDA 10.1 (or the version of CUDA you needed)

https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive

- Unzip and copy content of `cuda` folder into: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\` (or the version you downloaded and installed)
- If you have any conflicts, skip duplicate files

#### 8. Test again

- Should work this time, assuming you downloaded the correct versions