# Dlerror: cudnn64_7.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, cudnn

When I run `tf.test.is_gpu_availabe()` it returns false and the only problem that it is showing that cudnn64_7.dll not found

I am using python 3.8.17 for tensorflow 2.3.0
Cuda-10.1, CudNN-8.0.5
GPU-Nvidia Geforce MX130, cuda compute compatibility-5

[image]

Comment: cudnn64_7 is from CuDNN 7. You have CuDNN 8.

Comment: I believe you can find the answer here - [Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698536/tensorflow-gpu-import-tensorflow-importerror-could-not-find-cudnn64-7-dll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this table](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations) (scroll down to GPU, it's for Linux but should be the same for Windows) TF 2.3 works with CUDA 10.1 and CuDNN version 7.6. As @Elmir pointed out the error indicates that TF searches for cudnn libraries from version 7. To fix it, replace your CuDNN files with the right version.